# REACT NATIVE: How can i make calculation with the Value of TextInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to make a Total by adding the Values from TextInput in RN:
Here is my TextInput

```
                <TextInput style={styles.input}
                  placeholder="   Amount "
                  placeholderTextColor="#9a73ef"
                  keyboardType='numeric'
                  onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
                  value={text}
                />
                <Picker
                  selectedValue={selectedValue}
                  style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
                >

                  <Picker.Item value='' label='Select Option' />
                  <Picker.Item label="Food" value="Food" />
                  <Picker.Item label="Transport" value="Transport" />
                  <Picker.Item label="Rent" value="Rent" />
                  <Picker.Item label="Other" value="Other " />

                </Picker>
              </View>
```

And TOTALis where i want to put my total Value by adding Value of TextInputs

```
          <Text>TOTAL : </Text>

              <Button
                title="Save"
                color="#841584"
                accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
                onPress={() => {
                  if (text && selectedValue) setData([...data, { name: text, selectedValue: selectedValue }
                  
                  ])
            

                }} />

              <View styles={styles.list}>
                <FlatList

                  data={data}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => <React.Fragment>
                    <Text style={styles.item}> {item.name} Dollars to "{item.selectedValue}"</Text>
                    
                  </React.Fragment>}

                  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        

       
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
)};
```

I tried adding them they are Strings , i used to `parseInt()` but didnt work?
Here is the ScreenShot of my App[image]

Comment: Your `onPress` do nothing actually, is it normal ?

Comment: I mean, I don't see any calculation. Did I miss something ?

Comment: i tried to make some calculations there , but it was a string and could not that, though , if you can  explain how to make, it will be nice )

Comment: Change string number to number with this `Number("500")`

Comment: Yeah so you just need to `parseInt(stringValue)` or `Number(stringValue)`

Comment: Cool, it worked , do you Know how to have a flatlist without that first one - empty one on the pic? cause whenever i just start to test my app this fiest Block of Flatlist is always apperaring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declear variable for total Amount like this

```
 const [totalAmount,setTotalAmount] = useState(0)
```

update totalAmount value on save button

```
<Button
                title="Save"
                color="#841584"
                accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
                onPress={() => {
                  if (text && selectedValue) {
                     setData([...data, { name: text, 
                     selectedValue: selectedValue }
                     ])
                    setTotalAmount(totalAmount + parseInt(text))
                  }

                }} />
```

and use this variable in your html

```
<Text>TOTAL : {totalAmount}</Text>
```

Comment: Cool, it worked , do you Know how to have a flatlist without that first one - empty one on the pic? cause whenever i just start to test my app this fiest Block of Flatlist is always apperaring.

Comment: you can add check for empty text in render callback

Comment: i have added answer below

Answer (score 1):

no I was talking about this. check here

```
<View styles={styles.list}>
     (data.length > 0)?
                <FlatList

                  data={data}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => <React.Fragment>
                    <Text style={styles.item}> {item.name} Dollars to " 
                    {item.selectedValue}"</Text>
                    
                  </React.Fragment>}

                  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

                />
        : null
</View>
```

Comment: noo, didnt work, same result , with empty block of Flatlist

Comment: add (data.length > 0)?<Flatlist .../>: null      check before you Flatlist

Comment: onPress={() => {
                  if (data.length > 0)  
                  { if 
                    (text && selectedValue) setData([...data, { name: text, selectedValue: selectedValue }
                    
                  ])}
                  setTotalAmount(totalAmount + parseInt(text))
                 
                }
                }     //same(, but anyway you helped me!!!

Comment: Thank you :)..but that was not what i meant.. i edit my answer above plz have a look

Comment: Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'>'}` or `&gt;`? ERROR